# Pluck single parent category from get_the_category

Tags: categories

I am working on a theme that displays a single category for each post.

However to eliminate user error, I would like to pluck a single parent category out of a posts categories.

Here is my code as of now:

```
   function thb_DisplaySingleCategory($boxed = true, $id = false) { 
$categories = get_the_category();
$_id = (empty($id) ? $categories[0]->cat_ID : $id);
$_name = (empty($id) ? $categories[0]->cat_name : get_cat_name($id));

if ($boxed) {
    $thecategory = '<a href="'.get_category_link($_id).'" class="boxed" title="'.$_name.'" style="background:'.GetCategoryColor($_id).'; ">'.$_name.'</a>';
} else {
    $thecategory = '<a href="'.get_category_link($_id).'" class="" title="'.$_name.'" style="color:'.GetCategoryColor($_id).'; ">'.$_name.'</a>';
}


return $thecategory;
}
```

This gives me a single category, but it can be children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the category `'parent'` arribute, and if is `0` the category is a parent one.

I've also noted some things on your code:

1. When the is is passed `get_the_category` is unused, but it is called anyway
2. You use `get_the_category` assuming function are called in the loop, but there is no check for that
3. If, for any case, `get_the_category` return no categories, your function thrown errors
4. Before inserting retrieved values inside html shoul be escaperd with `esc_*` functions

I rewrote your function considering all those things and adding the check for parent category:

```
function thb_DisplaySingleCategory($boxed = true, $id = false) { 
  if ( (int) $id ) {
    $cat = get_category($id);
    if ( ! empty($cat) ) {
       $backup = $cat->term_id;
       if ( $cat->parent == 0 ) $id = $cat->term_id;
    }
  }
  if ( empty($id) && in_the_loop() ) {
    $id = '';
    $categories = get_the_category();
    if ( empty( $categories ) ) return;
    while ( empty($id) && ! empty($categories) ) {
      $cat = array_shift($categories);
      if ( $cat->parent == 0 ) $id = $cat->term_id;
    }
  }
  // if no parent cat found, but a not-parent cat id passed to function use that
  if ( ! (int) $id && isset($backup) ) $id = $backup;
  if ( ! (int) $id ) return;
  $name = get_cat_name($id);
  $url = esc_url( get_category_link($id) );
  $wcolor = $boxed ? 'background' : 'color';
  $class = $boxed ? ' class="boxed"' : '';
  $color = GetCategoryColor($id);
  $frmt = '<a href="%s"%s title="%s" style="%s:%s;">%s</a>';
  return sprintf( $frmt, $url, $class, esc_attr($name), $wcolor, $color, esc_html($name) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @G.M.

However, when I used your code, it does not return any category for some posts that have multiple parent categories and children categories assigned.

Thanks for pointing some of the mistakes as well, as I am learning PHP.

Comment: After further checking, I found that the problem is with the boxed attribute. If the function is called like this:

    echo thb_DisplaySingleCategory(false)

No Category is displayed.

Comment: @AntEksiler I've tested with both `$boxed = true` and `$boxed = false` and it works form me. I can't full test because I don't know what `GetCategoryColor` do, for test I just put `$color = '#F00';` and it works...